# pdfpages and XeLaTeX: including pdf with uppercase .PDF extension

Tags: xetex, pdfpages

here's the problem I'm finding. I have to include some PDF files in a LaTeX. The LaTeX code is generated at runtime, and has to include whatever PDF file it finds in a given directory. These files might have an uppercase .PDF extension. I have no control to prevent this, and cannot rename them. My engine is XeLaTeX. This all happens on a FreeBSD machine with TeXLive 2013.

On my workstation everything works ok if I do *not* provide the extension of the file to the \includepdf command. It guesses it is a PDF, and the include goes all right. However, if I provide the complete filename with the uppercase .PDF extension, I get a blank page instead of the include, and the logs complain that the file cannot be found.

Here's a minimal example (with the extension on):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,landscape,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\nonstopmode
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\clearpage]{compta.PDF}
\end{document}
```

And here's a log extract:

```
./Sans-titre.tex:6: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'compta.PDF'.
<to be read again> 
               }
l.6 ...pages=-,pagecommand=\clearpage]{compta.PDF}

The requested image couldn't be read because
the file was not found.

File: compta.PDF Graphic file (type QTm)
```

This is strange enough already, but ok, I thought, I'll just keep the extension out. 
The thing is, when the same .tex is typeset on the FreeBSD server, if I keep the extension out I get the following in the log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

! Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file `compta'.

See the pdfpages package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 ...pdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\clearpage]{compta}

! Undefined control sequence.
\AM@checklast ...pii \\ \@tempcntb =\AM@pagecount 
                                                  \relax \ifAM@DVIoutput \if...
l.6 ...pdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\clearpage]{compta}

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.6 ...pdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\clearpage]{compta}

)
Runaway argument?
\expandafter \AM@setphantomdoc \AM@doclist ,\END \ifthenelse {\boolean \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \AM@gobble.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> TMP_test.tex

! Emergency stop.
<*> TMP_test.tex

No pages of output.
Transcript written on TMP_test.log.
```

and if I put the .PDF extension in, I get this:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'compta.PDF'.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.6 ...pages=-,pagecommand=\clearpage]{compta.PDF}

<use  "compta.PDF" >
! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'compta.PDF'.
<to be read again> 
                   \GXT@clipend 
l.6 ...pages=-,pagecommand=\clearpage]{compta.PDF}

! Arithmetic overflow.
<recently read> \calc@Acount 

l.6 ...pages=-,pagecommand=\clearpage]{compta.PDF}

! Arithmetic overflow.
<recently read> \calc@Acount
```

This is getting me mad, especially when I see that if the exactly same PDF file has a lowercase extension everything goes smooth.
I've tried adding the following (both toghether and separately) to the preamble:

```
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{pdf,PDF,png,PNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,txt,TXT}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.PDF}{pdf}{*}{}
```

but to no avail (in fact, the only result I could get from the \DeclareGraphicsRule was that instead of the included PDF I got a print of the path of the PDF file, in the middle of the page.

The pdf file I'm trying to include is located at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10487109/compta.PDF (however, as I said, it works fine with a lowercase extension, so I don't think the file itself has a problem)

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.
Cheers

---

Comment: I've not used `pdfpages` so I don't know what that does in this regard, but I had to use `grffile` to insert plots with non-standard filenames. Could be worth a shot?

Comment: Imho you must use dots in the list of `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions`.

Comment: I'm worried about the answer of `file`: it should be `PDF document`, not `Graphic file (type QTm)`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you are right, dots are needed, however that was not the issue apparently. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some graphics driver support uppercase extensions (`pdftex.def`) others do not.
`xetex.def` with version 2014/04/07 v0.99 does not.

The simple form is to add the support for each extension manually, e.g.:

```
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.PNG}{QTm}{QTm}{#1}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.JPG}{QTm}{QTm}{#1}
\usepackage{grfext}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions*{.PNG,.JPG}
```

However this will not work for `.PDF` due to bugs.

The following example adds the supported extensions of `xetex.def` in their uppercase variants and patches commands of `xetex.def` to fix the bugs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grfext}

% bug in xetex.def
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\XeTeX@include@QTm{%
  \lowercase{\edef\type@ext{\Gin@ext}}%
}{%
  \edef\type@ext{%
    \noexpand\lowercase{%
      \noexpand\def\noexpand\type@ext{\Gin@ext}%
    }%
  }%
  \type@ext
}{}{}
\let\Ginclude@QTm\XeTeX@include@QTm 
\patchcmd\G@measure@QTm{%
  \lowercase{\edef\type@ext{#2}}%
}{%
  \edef\type@ext{%
    \noexpand\lowercase{%
      \noexpand\def\noexpand\type@ext{#2}%
    }%
  }%
  \type@ext
}{}{}

\@for\@ext:=\Gin@extensions\do{%
  \uppercase\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\@EXT\expandafter{\@ext}%
  }%
  \@ifundefined{Gin@rule@\@EXT}{%
    \expandafter
    \let\csname Gin@rule@\@EXT\expandafter\endcsname
        \csname Gin@rule@\@ext\endcsname
    % Patch rule to exchange lowercase extension with uppercase
    % (needed for ".PS" and ".EPS"
    \edef\@tempa{%
      \noexpand\patchcmd
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname Gin@rule@\@EXT\endcsname
      {{\@ext}}{{\@EXT}}{}{}%
    }\@tempa
  }{}%
  \expandafter
  \AppendGraphicsExtensions\expandafter*\expandafter{\@EXT}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \includegraphics{TIGER}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have just made a feature request/bug report.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, it would have taken me an incredible amount of time to figure it out. Thanks for submitting the feature request too.